# How do you use AppAnalyticsQueryRequest?

Tags: managed-package

Does anyone have experienced pulling **AppExchange App Analytics data** for their managed package using ***AppAnalyticsQueryRequest***? This was released in Summer 2019. If you have experience with this can you please tell me:

- Did you use SOAP UI?
- Which WSDL did you generate to reference in SOAP UI? Enterprise? Partner?

I am looking for step by step guide that is more then what SF has right now: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/app_analytics_download_mp_logs.htm

Comment: Do you mean SOAP Api?

Comment: I meant Soap UI software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce just released this package for a much more friendly interface to pull AppAnalytics data.
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G0nUXUAZ

Answer (score 1):

Essentially there are two options, depending on what you need the data for:

#### 1) Do it yourself: request data via the Salesforce API

The flow is roughly:

1. Insert an app analytics query request which specifies:

   - the timeframe you need the data for
   - the package IDs you need the data for (all of the requested packages need to be enabled for AppAnalytics through the partner portal case)
2. Wait until the request state is complete (through polling the request by its ID)
3. Fetch the CSV data which is provided as download URL in the request. The download URL expires after a certain time (15 minutes as of today).

Then there are two types of data points you can retrieve through the process above: **a) detailed log events** and **b) monthly summaries** which rollup CRUD operations on a monthly basis. The amount of data for a) can be significant, depending on the number of subscriber orgs, users and activity in the packages.

The setup also requires a bit of fine-tuning, in order to keep the CSV size below 2GB, which is the APIs upper limit for one given request.

#### 2) Use a plug-and-play solution

The data files described above contain usage data on a very granular level. If you're not willing or able to build the data fetching, storage, aggregation and evaluation yourself, you can use a plug-and-play solution like [ISVapp](https://www.isvapp.com). You connect it via OAuth to your partner business org and it does the heavy lifting + provides insights from the data (charts, dashboards, forecasts etc.).

Answer (score 0):

the best way to access this object is using Workbench. Salesforce should update their documentation to say this instead of suggesting SOAP.