# Get app analytics across deployments?

Tags: apex, logging

If I develop a Salesforce AppExchange app and multiple Salesforce customers install the the app into their Salesforce orgs, as the developer, can I get customized analytics/stats from all usage of my app? For example, could I find out how many times people clicked on a certain button in my app?

Comment: Do you mean appexchange app ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Yes, I mean an AppExchange app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Salesforce provide tools to collect stats for your packages. As stated in [Usage Metrics Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/usage_metrics_intro.htm):

> You can collect detailed usage metrics from each organization in which
>   your managed package is installed. By analyzing this information, you
>   can gain valuable insights into the utilization and performance of
>   your app across your entire customer base. For example, you can
>   identify:
>
> - The features most and least used — this can help you prioritize your development efforts when planning the next version of your app.
> - The customers using your app most intensively — these are your most valuable customers.
> - The customers whose usage of your app is minimal or declining — these are the customers most at risk of attrition.
>
> You can collect the following daily metrics on two types of components
>   in a managed package.
>
> - **Custom objects** — the total number of records existing per organization in each custom object. This enables you to track how the
>     usage of that custom object is growing with time in any subscriber
>     organization, which is a reliable indicator of how much it's being
>     utilized
> - **Visualforce pages** — the number of times per organization each Visualforce page was accessed, the number of unique users who accessed
>     it, and the average loading time (in milliseconds). By comparing the
>     metrics for different Visualforce pages, you can determine the
>     relative popularity of different parts of your app in a specific
>     customer organization, as well as trends across all customers.

Also, you can get familiar with [AppExchange App Analytics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/app_analytics_intro.htm). From the documentation page:

> AppExchange App Analytics provides usage data about how subscribers
>   interact with your AppExchange solutions. You can use these details to
>   identify attrition risks, inform feature development decisions, and
>   improve user experience.
>
> Consistent with Salesforce’s commitment to customer trust, AppExchange
>   App Analytics doesn’t expose customer data to AppExchange Partners.
>   App Analytics data is exclusively usage-related data. Any potentially
>   sensitive data is tokenized or redacted.
>
> App Analytics is available for managed packages that have passed
>   security review and are registered to a License Management App. Usage
>   data is provided as log files or month-based usage summaries. Both log
>   files and monthly summaries are downloadable comma-separated value
>   (.csv) files. To view the data in dashboard or visualization format,
>   use [Einstein Analytics](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_explorer.htm) or a third-party analytics tool.

Comment: Can I publish my own events that can be retrieved from App Analytics? Everything I've been reading about is how to retrieve the analytics data. I want to know if I can publish custom data to go into the analytics

Answer (score 0):

App Analytics is the newer API which was introduced in 2019. The data it provides is mainly event-based and thus different from Usage Metrics, which more or less contained snapshots. I outlined the process of requesting App Analytics data in [How do you use AppAnalyticsQueryRequest?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273494/how-do-you-use-appanalyticsqueryrequest/301512#301512)

Alternatively to the Salesforce APIs, you can leverage a third-party tool like [ISVapp](https://www.isvapp.com) which provides package analytics, charts, forecasts etc.